# Invisible reCaptcha PHP vs JS verification

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha, captcha

I have a simple question.
I added a custom form with Google Invisible Captcha to avoid spam.

Currently I have a something like this (just works fine):

```
<script>
 function onSubmit(token) {
   document.getElementById("demo-form").submit();
 }
</script>
<form id='demo-form' action="" method="POST">
  <button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key" data-callback='onSubmit'>Submit</button>
  <br/>
</form>
```

But to make it more "secure" I can add extra layer of verification via $_POST response as described below.

```
if( isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) ) {
  // verify response
  $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret_key.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
  $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

  // if all good => proceed registration
  if ($responseData->success) {
```

Do you think it worth adding this extra verification via PHP or it's fine to leave it as is ?

Comment: Questions that require primarily opinion based answers are off-topic for SO.